# How to get only the timestamp without the time zone as a string in Big Query?

Tags: python-3.x, string, google-bigquery, string-formatting

I want to cast the current_timestamp in Big Query to a string but it add `+00` which stand for UTC as the time zone to the string. I only want the timestamp without the zone i.e. without `+00`. How can I get that?

This is what I'm doing:

```
select STRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as now
```

The result:

```
    
2022-11-29 10:56:12.793309+00
```

I want:

```
2022-11-29 10:56:12.793309
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider more formal way below.

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%F %T.%E*S', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as now
```

- `%F` - The date in the format %Y-%m-%d.
- `%T` - The time in the format %H:%M:%S.
- `%E*S` - Seconds with full fractional precision (a literal '*').

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a hacky solution:

```
split(STRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), "+")[OFFSET(0)]
```

Any cleaner alternatives?